# Will TestFlight remove my previous builds if I upload a new version of an app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have a version of my app, let's say 1.0.2, which has 3 builds currently testing in TestFlight (builds 18, 19 and 20). Now we are planning for a newer version of app and hence the new version will be version 1.0.3 with the build number 1, **will Apple remove or expire my previous TestFlight builds of previous version 1.0.2?**

Apple says:

> We’ve made some changes to help you do more with TestFlight in iTunes Connect. With multiple build support, enhanced groups, and improved tester management, we’re making it even easier to test your apps.

It says multiple builds, does this mean multiple builds only or multiple versions + multiple builds? It's confusing.

Comment: NO, Apple will not remove your old build, but the build will valid for 90 days to Send it to the tester. After 90 days of uploaded build,  it will not able to send to the tester.

Comment: Simply NO!  It will remains as it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, your previous builds will stay testable, even if a new minor (or major) version is introduced.

[image: TestFlight - testing with multiple versions]